# Cookie PHP, чтение, запись, передача?

Tags: php, cookie

Использую

```
setCookie('namecc','1234',1200,'/');
```

Затем

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

- выдает черти какие элементы массива, что в формате как будто кодированное:) [SESSedd5b2...] => ODnkDJhiDJHSGD .. . и т.д

  print_r($_COOKIE['namecc']);

пишет Notice: Undefined index: namecc in - т.е. Куки не записалось ?,

И далее еще более сложно, мне необходимо передать эти куки стороннему скрипту, на другом домене в заголовке, т.е. полностью сємулировать браузер при передаче Куки стороннему скрипту.
Браузер Firefox 46, PHP 5.6, Appache
Как это исправить? В каком направлении искать?

Answer (score 1):

За 3-и часа, немного покурив, нашел следующую свою ошибку, setcookie в PHP устанавливает срок действия по метке времени в секундах, т.е. не 1200 от текущего времени, а 1200 от начала наших дней ... таким образом Куки устанавливались и в течение сессии обнулялись, необходимо указывать в setcookie, 3-ий параметр time()+ количество секунд после текущего времени, например 60*60*30 - 30 мин. от момента загрузки страницы.